# Calculate percentile rank using javascript for each user in array of json objects based on user's overall place

Tags: javascript

**Using javascript**, how can I calculate the percentile rank for each participant in a results list where person with place = 1 (Joe) has a 100% rank since they won a race, for instance, but then all other people's ranks are lower from there? Here are some sample results. Can someone please help?

```
const results = [{
  name: 'joe',
  place: 1,
  rank: '100%'
}, {
  name: 'roger',
  place: 2,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'heather',
  place: 3,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'craig',
  place: 4,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'sally',
  place: 5,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'cory',
  place: 6,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'joel',
  place: 7,
  rank: '?'
}];
```

Comment: can you provide an example output of this function, please? How does the end result suppose to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract one less than each person's rank from the number of people and divide by the number of people to get the percentage rank.

```js
const results = [{
  name: 'joe',
  place: 1,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'roger',
  place: 2,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'heather',
  place: 3,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'craig',
  place: 4,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'sally',
  place: 5,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'cory',
  place: 6,
  rank: '?'
}, {
  name: 'joel',
  place: 7,
  rank: '?'
}];
results
 .forEach(person=>person.rank 
   = (+((results.length - person.place + 1) / results.length * 100).toFixed(2)) + '%');
console.log(results);
```